# MongoDB TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to insert data to collection,before insert i need to check if it exists

```
  collection.find({sno: req.body.sno}).toArray((err, result)=> {

    if (result.length > 0) {
      flag = false;
      callback(flag);
    }
    else {
      console.log(result.length);
      collection.insertOne({sno: req.body.sno, password: req.body.password}, (err, insertResult)=> {
        if (insertResult.result.ok === 1) {  
          flag = true;
        }
        callback(flag);
      });
    }
  });
```

if `sno` is not exist ,i got

```
0
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
```

But,if `sno`is exist or only `collection.insertOne`(delete `collection.find`),it worked.

How to solve this problem? Please give me some help.

it seems to be a problem with callback function arguments??

```
collection.find({xx:xx}).toArray((err, result)=> {
    collection.insertOne({...}),(err)=>{}  //can't use res??
&&
collection.inserOne({...}),(err,res)=>{
  console.log(res.result); // {ok:1，n:1}
}
```

Comment: check it properly? `insertResult` seems to not contain `result` in `insertResult.result.ok`

Comment: I try to console.log`insertResult` (only `insertOne`),it contain ` result: { ok: 1, n: 1 }`

Comment: i got `undefined`?

Comment: Try to add failsafe code: `if (insertResult && insertResult.result && insertResult.result.ok === 1) {`

Answer (score 1):

try logging the error and see what you get.
any way, if you want to know the length of the cursor you don't have to convert it to an array, use [cursor.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count). in your case:

```
 collection.find({sno: req.body.sno}).count()
```

also, if you're ok with using promises I would suggest this approach.

```
 collection.find({sno: req.body.sno})
.then(result => {
  if (result.count() < 1) throw new Error() 
   })
 .then(() =>{
 // insert
 flag = true;
 })
 .catch(err => {
 flag = false; 
})
```